# Writing raw sql CTE in Django

Tags: sql, django, common-table-expression

I have a team hierarchy model

```
class Hrc(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, unique=True, editable=False)
    emp = models.ForeignKey('Employee', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='emp')
    mang = models.ForeignKey('Employee', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='mang')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_on']
```

Since I want to get the hierarchy under a particular given employee, I want to use CTE. I want to write a CTE in one of the Django Signals I have. Below is the signal I have

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Employee)
def employeeUpdated(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if not created:
        //I want to get the hierarchy under an employee (instance in this case). So the 
        // CTE should be written here
```

The CTE I want to write is

```
with hierarchy as 
(
  select emp, mang, 1 as lvl
  from hrc 
  where emp = instance
  
  union all
  
  select child.emp, parent.emp, lvl+1
  from hierarchy as parent
  join hrc as child
      on child.mang = parent.emp
), lvls as (
    select lvl, emp
    from hierarchy
    group by lvl, emp
)
select lvl, STRING_AGG(emp, '') within group (order by emp)
from lvls
group by lvl;
```

How can I write this cte in the signal and get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

That should do it. It will make use of the [raw SQL query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/sql/) feature from Django.
Change the parameter passed to the SQL statement with `%s` to your needs.

```
from django.db import connection


@receiver(post_save, sender=Employee)
def employeeUpdated(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if not created:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute("""
                WITH hierarchy
                AS (
                    SELECT emp
                        ,mang
                        ,1 AS lvl
                    FROM hrc
                    WHERE emp = %s
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT child.emp
                        ,parent.emp
                        ,lvl + 1
                    FROM hierarchy AS parent
                    INNER JOIN hrc AS child ON child.mang = parent.emp
                    )
                    ,lvls
                AS (
                    SELECT lvl
                        ,emp
                    FROM hierarchy
                    GROUP BY lvl
                        ,emp
                    )
                SELECT lvl
                    ,STRING_AGG(emp, '') within
                GROUP (
                        ORDER BY emp
                        )
                FROM lvls
                GROUP BY lvl;""",
                [instance.pk]
            )
            row = cursor.fetchall()
        # do whatever you need to do with the result
```

Comment: sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
I am getting this error

Comment: Perhaps you are passing something other than a string to the SQL statement. In case it is an integer, then use `str(your_int_variable)`.